# Angular2 don't load external js file when i change the view using Angular2 UI routes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, angular2-routing

[Angular2 don't load external js file when i change the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586760/angular2-dont-load-external-js-file-when-i-change-the-view/43587257#43587257)

In reference to above query, I am also facing the same issue while changing the views using routes of the Angular2 it loses the 'JS' and 'CSS' functionality of the view and also does not show any error.

Basically, I am using one template which is made using JQuery, CSS and bootstrap and when I change the view of my app using routes it does not caches and JS and CSS functionality although it is getting the all files. I have saved my all external theme file in 'assets' folder and it is caching the all functionality on reload.

How can I run all my external JS and CSS files when I change the view?

Comment: Is this for learning angular or real production code . Using jquery in an angular app is very bad practice.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have same issue.

Comment: @Yeysides No I have not found any solution for this it loads the external js  libraries but once we start navigating over routes it breaks the functionality